# Angular 2 : select all checkboxes when clicking on a button outside that div

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

my task is to select all the checkboxes(get it checked),also get the id of each checkboxes, the code i have used id given below

the div which clicking in outside that of div where checkbox is placed

**Html**

```
 <li  class="on-hov" *ngFor="let confirmedOrders of confirmedOrder | async|  search:'id,order_shop_no':query let i = index" >
                            <div class="row">
........................
....................



<div class="col-sm-5 text-right right-actions">
    <a class="select-all" (click)="showallDeleteCheckbox($event)">Select All</a>
</div>
............
..........
 <div *ngIf = "shown"><input  type="checkbox" id="{{confirmedOrders.order_id}}"  class="del-all"></div>
............
.............
```

**.ts**

```
  private confirmedOrder: Observable<any>;
..............
..............
self.confirmedOrder = self.storeService.getConfirmedOrder(self.shopId);
   self.confirmedOrder.subscribe((res:any) => {
   self.confirmed_array_length = res.length;
..............
..............
    howallDeleteCheckbox(ev){
  var self = this;
  self.shown = true;
  console.log('orderlength',self.confirmed_array_length);
  for (var i = 0; i < self.confirmed_array_length; i++) {
    self.confirmedOrder[i].selected = self.selectedAll;
    console.log("im here", self.confirmedOrder[i].selected);
  }


}
.............
```

Comment: can you add information for the variable `confirmedOrders`

Comment: Added the variable info

Comment: I cant find any information about that variable `confirmedOrders`

Comment: please check now, Hope that is

Comment: not celar at all , please add more informatio

Comment: try out answer might help you , as you just want to remove element ...you can also set style sheet dispaly:non if you just want to hide ..

Comment: thank you for the reply,
i just want to get all checkboxes checked on a click,
hope you can help me for that

Comment: @Aashiqcr - you just need to call `removeAllSelectedCheckBoxes` fuction on click , thats it, let me know if there is any issue in that

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove all checkboxes for the DOM then you can do it with help of javascript

```
removeAllSelectedCheckBoxes() {
    var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
    for(let i=0; i<checkedBoxes.length; i++) {
      checkedBoxes[i].parentNode.removeChild(checkedBoxes[i]);
    }
}
```

Note : javascript code works in typescript.